# Create a continuous new DEM using bathymetry and topography

Tags: gdal-calc

I have two rasters. One is the topography map and the other one is the bathymetry. I would like to create a new DEM where everything below the sea level will come from bathymetry.tif, while everything above the sea level will come from topography.tif. All files have the same dimensions. How could I do this using gdal_calc.py?

```
gdal_calc.py -A Bathymetry.tif –B Topography.tif --outfile="joined_Bathy_Topo.tif" --calc="A*(A<=0) + B*(B>0)"
```

At the end I get a DEM with pixel values as sum. I will know I have a good DEM when the smallest pixel is bathymetry and the largest is topography.

Comment: You know there are areas of land whose elevation is below sea level (like Death Valley), right?

Comment: As a "sum"? That doesn't seem wise.

Comment: @barrycarter This is true. The idea is to get a DEM with negative pixel values from the bathymetry even if the valley areas (Death valley) are taken from the same DEM

Comment: I'm assuming the bathymetry TIF uses a "no data" value for land and similar for topography, correct? Could you use some sort of `IF` statement to take the non-"no data" value? Also, what results are you getting now that you're unhappy, and is this data publicly available if we want to help you more directly?

Comment: @vince this is the result I get when I try to compile with the above code. Of course I would like to have something different.

Comment: @barrycarter The bathymetry uses existing data values for land, although there are still NoData Values=nan. This is a DEM from the SRTM15Plus database. On the other hand the land data uses no data values for the marine coverage, in addition to the non-existent NoData Value=-32767. 
In fact I get a result that adds the pixels from both databases. The data are available only the volume of one is huge.

Comment: Are the bathymetry and elevation data at different scales of resolution? If not, you could use the nodata values in elevation and replace them with bathymetry?